# Software/Batch/Something that connects to web and downloads

Tags: windows, batch-file, download

does it exists a Software/Batch/Something for Windows OS that could access the web and download a file (like a xml) in a specified folder, recursively in time (like 1 time a day)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

[wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell:

```
PS Home:\> $wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
PS Home:\> $wc.DownloadFile( ... )
```

You can use the Task Scheduler to run it in specified intervals.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you need to try and post any problems you run across. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx